# cURL inside script

Tags: shell-script, curl

I'm trying to troubleshoot some problem on FreeBSD server that is intermittently (at random times) being blocked by a network firewall from downloading some file over HTTPS from a webserver. 
In an effort to understand what happens when the block happens,
I need to run the following cURL:

```
curl --interface nic1 --verbose --insecure 'https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin' > /dev/null
```

and then read the stderr of the command. 
However, since the problem happens on random times that cannot be expected,
I want to run this curl once every 10 seconds and store the stderr in a file so that I can review it later, I used the following script (named `cURLScript`) to achieve this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    date
    echo "================================="
    curl --interface nic1 --verbose --insecure 'https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin' > /dev/null  2>&1
    echo ""
    sleep 10
done
```

I then run the script:

```
/bin/sh cURLScript > log &
```

I expect that `log` file would contain the stderr, however, it does not; the `log` is missing the stderr:

```
Svr12loc:service 21] cat log
Thu Mar 24 16:42:34 CET 2022
=================================

Thu Mar 24 16:43:03 CET 2022
=================================

Thu Mar 24 16:43:33 CET 2022
=================================

Thu Mar 24 16:44:02 CET 2022
=================================

Thu Mar 24 16:44:32 CET 2022
=================================

Thu Mar 24 16:45:00 CET 2022
=================================
```

Can someone suggest what is it I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear. 
I *guess* you are saying that

- you don’t care about the HTML output from cURL
  (which you’re sending to `HTMLFILE`),
- you care about the “verbose” messages;
- the verbose messages are going to the terminal (and not the `Log` file), and
- you want them to go to the `Log` file (and not the terminal).

In Unix (and Unix-like operating systems, and even some others),
programs have two automatic output streams: standard output
(abbreviated “stdout”) and standard error (abbreviated “stderr”). 
As the names suggest, stdout is meant for the primary output,
and stderr is meant for error messages and diagnostics. 
By default, both of these point to the terminal. 
When you say `> HTMLFILE`, you are redirecting cURL’s stdout to `HTMLFILE`. 
But the verbose messages are being written to stderr.

What you want is to send cURL’s stderr to the stdout of the script
(which is the `Log` file).

This is easy in any of the standard, POSIX-compliant shells
derived from the Bourne shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    date
    echo "================================="
    curl --interface nic1 --verbose --insecure https://www.20min.ch  2>&1  > HTMLPAGE
    echo ""
    sleep 10
done
```

`2>&1` does exactly what I said above — redirect the stderr to the stdout.

It’s trickier in C shell:

```
#!/bin/csh
set t=`mktemp`
while ((1))
    date
    echo "================================="
    ( curl --interface nic1 --verbose --insecure https://www.20min.ch > HTMLPAGE )  >& "$t"
    cat "$t"
    echo ""
    sleep 10
end
```

In csh, `>&` means send stdout and stderr to the following file. 
Sending them separate places (which is what you want) is tricky. 
The trick is to send the stdout where you want it,
then wrap the command in parentheses,
and then use `>&` on the wrapped command. 
I don’t know how to simply send the stderr to the stdout. 
(There probably is a way, and I anticipate being told what it is.) 
Above, I used the trick of sending the stderr to a temporary file,
and then sending the file to stdout with `cat`.

I encourage you to write scripts in the standard shell. 
The C shell is not good for scripting.

P.S. If you don’t want to save the standard output from curl,
why not send it to `/dev/null`?

Comment: Thank you for not only putting solution, but also explaining it.

Comment: You could use `-o/--output` to 'redirect' stdout within curl, instead of having shell do it, then you don't need the `( )` subshell. FWIW.

Comment: I tried to use your S shell script but the 'Log' file doesnt really contain the stderr of the cURL, the only edit i did to the suggested script is sending stdout of cURL to /dev/null instead to HTMLPAGE

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' question is edited

Comment: Oops; my mistake. I got the order of the redirections wrong; you need to have the ``2>&1`` *before* the `>`.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', this works as expected, thank you again.
not only for putting the solution, but also explaining how it works! appreicate it:))

Comment: One final nit-pick: ``/bin/sh`` isn’t called “the S shell”.  I’m not sure that there is any universal name for it, but it can be called “the standard shell”, “the system shell”, “the SH shell” or simply “SH” (spelled out: “ess aich”).  It’s probably not good to call it just “the shell”, because too many confused people think of `bash` as “the shell”.  Likewise, “the default shell” is subject to misinterpretation, because the default login shell for most users is `bash`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Or you could use “the POSIX shell” to refer to any derivative of the Bourne shell that satisfies the POSIX specifications for the shell — this could include `bash`, if you were careful not to use any “bashisms” (bash features not specified by POSIX), but would exclude the C shell and any of its derivatives (e.g., ``tcsh``).

Comment: Got it :)) 
thanks alot for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the output of `curl` to the file `HTMLPAGE`. The `>` is a redirection operator defined to do exactly that.

If you want the page contents to be included in your script output (i.e. in the `log` file) don't redirect it on the line calling `curl`

Comment: I concede that the question is unclear, but I believe that you missed the point.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica it seems that perhaps i did, but not intentionally. If you hadn't provided an answer already I'd ask how you would interpret "_the Log file doesn't really contain output of the cURL_"

Comment: Well, of course I didn’t believe that you would have done it intentionally. In fact, I believe that the phrase “missed the point” pretty much *implies* “(unintentionally)”.

Comment: :-) [and some filler text]